# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I new to Tkinter and it says to convert to a string but my input is an integer and when I run it  gives me this error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'NoneType'

```
import tkinter as tk

window9 = tk.Tk()
msrp = tk.IntVar()
amgpage = tk.Label(window9, text="Mercedes Benz AMG Depreciation Calculator").pack(anchor='center')

amgpage = tk.Label(window9, text="What is the MSPR of the car?: ")
amgpage.pack()

msrp = tk.Entry(window9)
msrp.pack()

msrp.focus_set()

def callback():
    value=(msrp.get())

b = tk.Button(window9, text="Save your msrp value", command=callback,fg="red")
b.pack()
amgpage = tk.Label(window9, text="What is the age of the car?: ")
amgpage.pack()

old = tk.Entry(window9)
old.pack()
old.focus_set()
def callback2():
    age=(old.get())

b = tk.Button(window9, text="Save the age of the car", command=callback2,fg="blue")
b.pack()    
amgpage = tk.Label(window9, text="")
amgpage.pack(anchor='w')
def msrpv():
    m = callback()
    p = int(m)
    a = callback2()
    n = int(a)
    a=p*(1-0.15)**n
    amgpage=tk.Label(window9,text="$"+a)
    amgpage.pack()


amgmsrp = tk.Button(window9, text="Get the current value of the car.", command=msrpv,fg="green")
amgmsrp.pack()


window9.geometry("400x400")

window9.title("Mercedes Benz AMG Depreciation Calculator")

window9.mainloop()
```

I want to use the numbers that the users gives me and plug it into the equation that I used in the program "a=p*(1-0.15)**n".

Comment: `callback2()` returns None... Same for `callback`... Maybe you should use age and value variables directly instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callbacks don't have return statements, so they are actually returning `None`. So in these lines:

```
m = callback()
p = int(m)
a = callback2()
n = int(a)
```

`m` and `a` both get assigned `None`, so you are calling `int(None)`. You probably mean to do something like:

```
def callback():
    value=(msrp.get())
    return value
```

and

```
def callback2():
    age=(old.get())
    return age
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need "callbacks" at all.

Get the values directly

```
def msrpv():
    p = int(msrp.get()) 
    n = int(old.get())
    a=p*(1-0.15)**n
    amgpage=tk.Label(window9,text="$"+a)
    amgpage.pack()
```

Note that `value` and `age` are only locally scoped to their own functions, so putting them in button callbacks aren't doing anything